# Advent of Code 2021, Day 1. Why does my program report a value exactly 2 lower than in reality?

Tags: python

So I'm having a go at the advent of code challenges for 2021 (yes I know it's a bit late but hey, it's fun)

I'm honestly embarassed I've already failed the very first challenge. As said in the title, the issue is that my code reports an answer that is 2 lower than the actual answer.

The problem is simple. It gives you a list of numbers, and you have to check how many times a number is higher than the previous one. So

```
1
2
3
2
1
```

The solution would be

```
1 (First one doesn't count)
2 (Increase)
3 (Increase)
2 (Decrease)
1 (Decrease)
```

As there are two increases, the answer would be two. Here is my code

```
# #Advent of code 2021
# #Day 1

#open input file
with open("input.txt") as file:
  depths = file.read().split('\n')
  depths.pop() #the last line of the file is empty

print(len(depths))
increases = 0
#check how many measurements are larger than previous measurements
for i in range(1, len(depths)):   #the first one doesn't count since no preceding values to compare against
  num1 = depths[i-1]
  num2 = depths[i]
  
  if num2 > num1:
    increases += 1

  print(i, "out of", len(depths), "complete", end='\r')
print()
print("The depth increases", increases, "times")
```

I've given other people's programs a run, and they work perfectly, so why does my program report a value too low? Why is it missing some numbers.

Comment: Because you're comparing strings lexicographically, not numbers?

Comment: Please use the PEP-8 standard of 4 spaces indentation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are comparing 2 string variables, which means that python sees both num1 and num2 as texts instead of numbers.

```
if num2 > num1:
    increases += 1
```

Try this instead: int() allows python to convert whatever is inside the parentheses to an integer (which means a whole number)

```
if int(num2) > int(num1):
    increases += 1
```